# Wine doesn't load Steam Ingame Overlay in any game

Tags: wine, games, steam

When I execute Wine in Steam, everything goes alright, except Steam Game Overlay

I have check if it is activated in steam, if my hot key combination is alright and everything, but I still don't get in-game community to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried looking further down in the link provided by @reverendj1 where it says `­winetricks sets up some compatibility overrides/defaults that are written directly in the STEAM client localconfig.vcf configuration file...­` and using those flags?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with winetricks. What do i have to do to make winetricks do this thing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to this: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19444 that is a known issue using Steam with Wine...

Comment: It says the tihng that acts weird sometimes is Steam Cloud, which is not related to that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Keep scrolling. There is a lot of info on that page. I was referring to this: "Steam Community In-Game does not work - disable or it may cause games to crash or slow-down." It says it under known issues.

Comment: I have found that line, but not the solution "above" as it says. I'm either blind or just stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. You write, the overlay will not displayed. Maybe it is similar with the problem, that the app can even crash (and since the latest version of steam, it will definitely crash on actual wine versions). So you could try the following:

**Solution: The compilation way**

You simple "patch" the source code of the official open source imm32.dll of wine.

```
$ git clone git://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git ~/wine-git
$ cd ~/wine-git
```

Optional, but highly recommented:

$ nano Makefile
and change "prefix = ..." to "prefix = /tmp/wine".
do the same with "ac_default_prefix = ..." in the file "configure".

Now apply the patch:

```
$ nano dlls/imm32/imm.c
```

Search for this line: "BOOL WINAPI ImmProcessKey("...
and insert after the "TRACE("... line this new line:

```
return FALSE;
```

Please to not forget the ";" char.

Thats all! Now compile:

```
$ make ./configure
$ make depend
$ make
$ make install
```

If you are using PlayOnLinux, you can simply add a new wine version:

```
$ cp -r /tmp/wine ~/.PlayOnLinux/wine/linux-x86/1.7.x-imm-patch
```

In PlayOnLinux, select the Steam entry and press on the configure button in the menu bar and select the wine version "1.7.x-imm-patch".

You can read it on my blog, too:
http://blog.en.edaro.net/2014/02/Wine-and-the-Steam-Community.html

Happy wine-playing!

Comment: Hi, I tried doing this but when I try and compile it doesn't seem to want to.

"make /.configure" just says "Nothing to be done for 'configure'. And "make depend" says "*** No rule to make target 'depend'. Stop.". Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I followed the official build instructions: https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/installing-wine-source . It could be, that the latest source needs other build instructions. But on the other hand, it could be possible, that this the overlay bug is solved in the latest wine release.

Comment: The overlay problem isn't solved for me and I still can't build wine from source so I've given up for now, thanks for the reply though!